# How To Build Qt WebEngine for PyQt5?

Tags: qt, python-3.x, pyqt5, qtwebengine

[Qt WebEngine](https://github.com/rodrigogolive/WebEngineWrapper) This link show python wrapper for Qt WebEngine .
Please can canyone tell me how can i add this in pyqt5 environment?
Thanks!!!

Comment: as your question was posted about 2.2 years ago.... and nobody answered ain't it time to delete the question or.... self-post answer perhaps?

Answer (score 6):

It seems I got it working:

Either install `pyqt` version 5.10, which still ships the web engine,

either install a newer (I use 5.12) and install `PyQtWebEngine` separately.

```
pip3 install PyQtWebEngine
```

Now these imports work:

```
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
```

I can't tell you the whys, I didn't find any explanation, just a clue here: [PyQt 5.11 missing WebEngine modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51900007/pyqt-5-11-missing-webengine-modules/55363959#55363959)