# Cannot import QtWebKitWidgets in PyQt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

I've recently upgraded PyQt5 from 5.5.1 to 5.6.0 using the Windows 32-bit installer here: https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5. I've also upgraded my python from 3.4 to 3.5.

When I run my old code (which used to work) with the latest version I get an exception:

```
    from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import *
ImportError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets'
```

All of my QT calls in my python occur consecutively and are (and I know I shouldn't be importing * but that's beside the issue here I think):

```
        from PyQt5.QtCore import *
        from PyQt5.QtGui import *
        from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
        from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import *
```

So the QtCore, QtGui and QtWidgets imports are all OK.

Also, when I search the source for QtWebKitWidgets there appears several references to this module.

Finally my python path looks like:

```
C:\PYTHON35;C:\PYTHON35\DLLs;C:\PYTHON35\LIB;C:\PYTHON35\LIB\LIB-TK;
```

and environment path:

```
C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5;C:\Python35;C:\Python35\Lib;C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages;C:\Python35\Scripts ....
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`QtWebKit` got deprecated upstream in Qt 5.5 and [removed in 5.6](http://wiki.qt.io/New_Features_in_Qt_5.6#Removed_Modules).

You may want to switch to [PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/api/qtwebenginewidgets/qwebengineview.html).

For basic use of `PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets.QWebView`, it can simply be updated to use `PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView` in the source code, but there may be some differences in the new component which require further adjustments.

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not know it had been deprecated. This is probably a different question but I had tried replacing the import with QtWebEngineWidgets but got another error:    
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The operating system cannot run %1. I'm initially guessing a different bit type... but I did run the correct installer (both python and qt 32 bit on 64 bit system).

Comment: I think you can ask a new question for this error :) or look at answers like this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22800768/getting-error-dll-load-failed-the-operating-system-cannot-run-1-python-2-7

Comment: I got it working by installing PyQtWebEngine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33108133/how-to-build-qt-webengine-for-pyqt5/55363933#55363933

Comment: If i want to downgrade pyinstaller which version should i use? i ask because msys mingw64 doesn't support PyQtWebEngine

Answer (score 25):

I was trying to run qutebrowser and it had the same error, the answer is simple, the packages changed.
You have two solutions:

1)

```
pip install PyQtWebEngine
```

2)

```
pip install PyQt5==5.11.3
```

Hope this helps any future problems

Answer (score 15):

In PyQt5 **"QtWebKitWidgets"** is *Deprecated*. I just replace this line

```
from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebView, QWebPage
from PyQt5.QtWebKit import QWebSettings
```

With this code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView as QWebView,QWebEnginePage as QWebPage
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineSettings as QWebSettings
```

Answer (score 4):

In PyQt5 *"QtWebKitWidgets"* is no longer available. Instead it is replaced with **"QtWebEngineWidgets".** So you have to make this change in your code.

For more information: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebenginewidgets-qtwebkitportingguide.html

Answer (score 4):

If you *really* want to use `PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets`, you could run this from the command line:

```py
pip install PyQtWebKit
```

and let it do what it does.

Comment: ```ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyQtWebKit
ERROR: No matching distribution found for PyQtWebKit```