# Implementing web inspection in browser using PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

QtWebKit is no longer supported in PyQt5.

Although there are alternates to some of the classes of QtWebKit in QtWebEngineWidgets. But, i couldn't find any alternate to the QWebInspector class that is available in PyQt4.

Are there any such classes OR even any other option so that i can implement web inspector using PyQt5 ?

**Edit**: Qt5.6 and beyond has removed QtWebKitWidgets

Comment: QWebInspector is available in PyQt5. http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/api/qwebinspector.html

Comment: @eyllanesc this is what i get when i try to import the module.  ImportError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets'. Actually i am using PyQt5.7 and according to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37876987/cannot-import-qtwebkitwidgets-in-pyqt5) its been removed.

Comment: I added an example

Answer (score 2):

I was somewhat surprised to find that [QtWebKit is making a comeback](http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/development/2016-June/026156.html). It is still not part of Qt-5.6 or Qt-5.7, but it seems that it may continue to be maintained as separate project. This means PyQt5 can continue to support QtWebKit, even though the official Qt5 docs say it has been removed.

Depending on your platform, this probably means you will need to install some extra packages if you want to use the "new" QtWebKit module in PyQt5.

PS:

As for QtWebEngine - if you're using ubuntu/debian, it seems you will have to wait for it to be supported. See [Bug #1579265](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qtbase-opensource-src/+bug/1579265).

Comment: Yeah I am using Ubuntu 16.04. Thanks for the clarification. So, basically i cannot use QtWebKit Or QtWebKitWidgets class in any way using PyQt5.7 on my machine ?

Comment: @Ankit. Not sure why you reached that conclusion. There are already [pyqt5 webkit packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/debug/python-pyqt5.qtwebkit-dbg) in ubuntu, so it should be possible to compile for any version you like.

Comment: i installed extra packages for qtwebkit too mentioned here  https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pyqt5 . But, still not working in python3 - works in python2 though

Comment: @Ankit. You need to install [python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit).

Comment: it means i still cannot get it worked after installing the above package. Import Error still persists when using python3. Btw , i had installed pyqt5 using pip3 initially - would that make a difference ?

Comment: @Ankit. Very likely. You should get rid of all the pip installed stuff, and only use the ubuntu packages. Then I think it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I show the following example to use QWebInspector in PyQt5 version 5.7.1

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebKit import QWebSettings
from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebView, QWebInspector
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QSplitter, QVBoxLayout, QWidget


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.view = QWebView(self)
        self.view.settings().setAttribute(
            QWebSettings.DeveloperExtrasEnabled, True)
        self.inspector = QWebInspector()
        self.inspector.setPage(self.view.page())
        self.inspector.show()
        self.splitter = QSplitter(self)
        self.splitter.addWidget(self.view)
        self.splitter.addWidget(self.inspector)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.splitter)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.view.load(QUrl('http://www.google.com'))
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: what OS and version are you using ?

Comment: @Ankit distro: Arch Linux

Comment: @Ankit install pyqt5.7, download from https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt5/PyQt-5.7.1/

Comment: i did that too. same results:  ImportError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets'