# Use PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets on Windows: is it possible?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qtwebkit, qtwebengine

I am trying to build an app in PyQt5 (version 5.6+) in Python 3.6. It contains a web browser, using QtWebEngineWidgets.
It works fine on Mac, however, there are problems on Windows. 
When I run the code on Windows and import the module:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWebEngineWidgets
```

I get the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'QtWebEngineWidgets'
```

Now, reading some forums it looks like PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets is not available for Windows, yet. Is it correct?
How can I have a web browser window, then?

I found online I could use QtWebKit, but according to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37876987/cannot-import-qtwebkitwidgets-in-pyqt5) it seems QtWebKit was removed in Qt5.6.
So what? Do I have to downgrade PyQt version?

I can't go under 5.6 in Python 3.6 anyway. Do I have to change Python version as well?

Comment: Would you explain how you installed pyqt5, have you tried installing a newer version of pyqt5 ?.

Comment: Newer version than the newest version (5.9)? That's hard...
I specified 5.6+, meaning that I tried all of them starting from 5.6

Comment: I installed it through PyCharm, btw

Answer (score 4):

you can try one of these solution ,

install old version :

```
pip install PyQt5==5.11.3
```

or install :

```
pip install PyQtWebEngine
```

Answer (score 0):

u can download PyQt5.6 from here:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt5/PyQt-5.6

QtWebKit got deprecated upstream in Qt 5.5 and removed in 5.6. Beacuse The QtWebEngineWidgets module is better than QtWebkit.

The example directory has many examples about QtWebEngineWidgets

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible to use QtWebEngineWidgets on Windows.