# How to open OSM in PyQt5 widget?

Tags: pyqt5, openstreetmap

[image: For eyllansec]
How do I get longitude and latitude of a certain place using OpenStreetMap in PyQt5. I found a solution using Google Maps but I need a free solution for this because I just want to get latitude and longitude of a certain place, nothing else.
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by *how to get longtitude and latitude of a certain place*? What google maps solution do you mean?

Comment: Hi eyllanesc i have read your answer in this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53627316/how-to-create-widget-in-pyqt5-to-show-google-map . i need user geolocation for some processes so to do this, I first need to load a map for him so that he can pinpoint his position on the map.

Comment: You want a map where the user clicks and then prints that position. Am I correct?

Comment: What I want to get from the user and store that in the database is a point that contains two arguments:(latitude and longtitude).

Comment: The GeoCoder (get the coordinates given the name of the place) is not possible with OSM since it does not offer that service, so only the rest is possible.

Comment: Foregive me eyllansec probably i coudn't present what i meant as well. I edit my question and upload a picture from what i want please check that.

Comment: An image without explanation does not help, what I can deduce is that you want the user to click on the map and add a marker printing the position. Is that what you want? If it is not, explain in more detail what you want. .

Comment: Yes almost and explanation added on image please check again.