# Spyder does not open from anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

Recently, I had to reinstall anaconda on a new computer.
I downloaded the latest version from anaconda's website, and installed it just as I did before.
Now, when I open anaconda interface and try to run Spyder.exe, I get this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\aabramzonx0108132\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\QtWebEngineWidgets.py", line 22, in 
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\aabramzonx0108132\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 
    10, in 
    sys.exit(main())
    File "C:\Users\aabramzonx0108132\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-            
    packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 186, in main
    from spyder.app import mainwindow
    File "C:\Users\aabramzonx0108132\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-        
    packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 90, in 
    from qtpy import QtWebEngineWidgets # analysis:ignore
    File "C:\Users\aabramzonx0108132\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site- 
  packages\qtpy\QtWebEngineWidgets.py", line 26, in 
from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebPage as QWebEnginePage
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets'
```

Could it be that I installed something wrong?

Answer (score 5):

This has to do with PyQt5 module. To fix this issue try removing PyQt5

```
pip uninstall PyQt5
```

If that does not work try to reinstall it using

```
conda install -f qt=5 pyqt=5
```

Similar post here: [54869374](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54869374/cant-start-spyder-because-of-pyqt5-qtwebkitwidgets)

Comment: I improved a bit your answer because the most probable cause of this is installing PyQt5 with pip.

Answer (score 0):

## Anaconda 2020.07, Linux, x84_64

I do not know why, but installing

`pip install pyqtwebengine`

fixed `spyder`, which was part of the `Anaconda` installation.

### Details:

This was tested on a fresh `fedora-33` virtual machine with `Anaconda` version `Anaconda3-2020.07-Linux-x86_64`. `pyqtwebengine` was not installed before. Trying to uninstall it, gave a `WARNING: Skipping pyqtwebengine as it is not installed.`