# PyQt 5.11 missing WebEngine modules

Tags: module, pyqt5, webengine

So I read the note on "PyQt 5.11 missing WebEngine modules" at https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5. But it doesn't help me understand why, or what to do regarding the missing WebEngine modules? The only thing that works is to revert to PyQt 5.10.0 or use x64 version. Can anyone explain and help me understand how I am meant to continue using PyQt5 x86 when the modules I use are now missing in 5.11.x and there appears to be no resource to re-acquire them. Are the WebEngine modules no longer supported in 32 bit or something?

Comment: I got it working by installing PyQtWebEngine separately: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33108133/how-to-build-qt-webengine-for-pyqt5/55363933#55363933

Answer (score 2):

The problem is simple, PyQt5 uses the binaries provided by Qt, and currently Qt no longer provides binaries for 32 bits, only for 64 bits.

**Can you use Qt WebEngine for 32 bits ?**

Yes you can but you will have to compile Qt manually and the dependencies of Qt WebEngine, and after that you will have to compile PyQt5.

References:

- https://forum.qt.io/topic/91096/how-to-make-qtwebengine-work-on-windows-10-32-bit